# how to call a method on grid column selector menu's hide evnet in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu, grid

Want to fire a method on header column selector on hide so that I can capture and save the selected items  to display when user returns to the page.
Tried following things which did NOT WORK 
Ext.getCmp("gridBox").headerCt.getMenu().on('hide', this.addUpdateAnalysisSetting, this);
Ext.getCmp("gridBox").column.menu.on('hide', this.addUpdateAnalysisSetting, this);

Even  tried to capture the event of second menu as below but  even that didnt work 
Ext.getCmp("gridBox").headerCt.getMenu().items.last().menu.on('hide', this.addUpdateAnalysisSetting, this);
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Saving the state of the grid (shown/hidden columns, their widths) does not need to be that complicated. You only need to do three things:

1. Initialize a [state provider](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.state.Manager-method-setProvider)
2. Set [stateful:true](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-stateful) on the grid
3. Set a [stateId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-stateId) on the grid

Comment: will that save the state across browser closes? Want to save across browser closes per user. Thansks

Comment: Yes, you can close the browser and open it again and you'll see the grid "as you left it". If it is per-user depends on the State Provider used. See also: http://extjs.eu/software/http-state-provider